# Adding Properties to Global Objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this is a common question, and I'm a JS newbie, but I'm completely stumped even after searching StackOverflow for hours.

I'm using the Google Maps API, and want to keep track of my markers by association with an ID. So I have `var pinArray = new Object()` as a global variable, and add markers like this:

```
function CreateMarkers (data){              
        data.forEach(function(store) {          
            <!-- CREATE MAP MARKER -->
            var mapLat = store.latitude;
            var mapLong = store.longitude;
            var mapLatLng = { lat: parseFloat(mapLat), lng: parseFloat(mapLong) };                      
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: mapLatLng,
                title: store.name,          
                icon: {
                    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                    scale: 8.5,
                    fillColor: 'Green',
                    fillOpacity: 0.8,
                    strokeWeight: 0.6,
                },              
                zIndex: 0   
            });
            cluster.addMarker(marker);
            var key = store.Id;
            pinArray['${key}'] = marker;                        
        })
    }
```

Where `cluster` is `var cluster = new MarkerClusterer(map);`.

When I try to do `console.log(pinArray);` back outside of the function, I get an empty object: *`Object {}`*. I've tried not using string interpolation as well, like `pinArray[store.Id] = marker;`, but get the same problem.

I need to keep this global associate between pins and IDs because I need to reference and update markers by their ID in other functions. Or at least, I think I do, I'm open to other ways of doing this. Help is very much appreciated; thank you in advance.

Comment: Just FYI - `<!-- CREATE MAP MARKER -->` is the syntax for a comment in HTML - JavaScript comments are `//like this`

Comment: @tymeJV Oh, thanks. I meant to go back and change those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically when I've done something like this in the past I'll use a standard javascript array instead of an ID'd object:

```
var pinArray = [];
```

Then use push to add the markers to it as you go:

```
pinArray.push(Marker);
```

When you create the pin you can include your key in its property definition:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: mapLatLng,
            title: store.name,          
            icon: {
                path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                scale: 8.5,
                fillColor: 'Green',
                fillOpacity: 0.8,
                strokeWeight: 0.6,
            },              
            zIndex: 0,
            key: store.Id
        });
```

and you can write a simple looping lookup function to find the individual map marker if you need to pull them by ID.  Something like:

```
function GetMarkerByKey(key) {
    var i = 0;
    while (pinArray[i].key != key) {i++}
    return pinArray[i];
}
```

Also, if you're using it in a dynamic event handler for click or hover you can use the this property to identify which marker they are activating it with.

~~~Edited to fix a syntax error~~~

Comment: This is a good idea, I didn't know I could just add whatever properties I wanted to the map marker. I'm still used to strongly-typed .NET!

Comment: By the way, `key = store.Id` should be `key: store.Id`!

Comment: Ah, I am a .NET developer too :) I know just what you mean.  Javascript is such a different world, but you get used to it after a while.  Sorry my script wasn't perfect, I didn't actually try to run it in a browser, I just kind-of wrote it directly into the Stack Overflow answer field haha.  I would be fairly surprised if that lookup function worked immediately.

Comment: The lookup actually works great! This solution worked really well. Now I'm just trying to get some efficiency going. I've got 10k+ markers, and clustering works well to speed up the load, but I'm trying to learn dynamic viewports so that I'm only loading the map with what I need at any given point.

Comment: Ah, fun.  I've not worked with the view ports before, I'm sure it's interesting.  Good luck with your efficiency!

Answer (score 2):

`var pinArray` assigns the variable within the scope of function it's defined. The safest way to ensure you're defining a variable as global, regardless of where you are inside a function, is to assign it to `window`.

```
window.pinArray = new Object();
```

Comment: IDK if that's his issue or not, but that's a pretty neat trick. +1

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I think I'm going to use the standard array method listed below, but this is great to know for truly global variables. Thanks!